# SQL Query between tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering if it is possible with SQL to make a query that gets the output of the TABLE A and use it as a SQL query for Table 2?

Let me explain myself bij using some code.

First i got the following table (TABLE A):

```
ID      TIMESTAMP 
--------------------------------      
1235    2015-03-27 07:04:27 
1236    2015-03-28 22:30:21 
1237    2015-03-29 22:49:37
```

Which I got with the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLEA where ((TABLEA.timestamp < '2015-03-29 00:00:00') and (TABLEA.timestamp > '2015-03-26 00:00:00'));
```

Now  I also have  another Table called TABLE B. In this Table the same id is visible but also with some extra information:

```
ID      Titel
------------------------
1235    Test1   
1236    Test2   
1237    Test3
```

Now what I want is to have a query that use the output from TABLE A (1235,1236,1237) and return from the other table the following result:

```
ID      Titel     Timestamp
-------------------------------------
1235    Test1     2015-03-27 07:04:27
1236    Test2     2015-03-28 22:30:21
1237    Test3     2015-03-29 22:49:37
```

is that possible?

Comment: Are you talking about joining tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using a simple join.

```
SELECT A.ID, B.TITLE1, A.TIMESTAMP
FROM TABLE1 A
JOIN TABLE2 B
ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.TIMESTAMP BETWEEN '2015-03-26 00:00:00' AND '2015-03-29 00:00:00';
```

Comment: Thanks! This indeed what I want:)